# how to fix API deprecation error

Tags: python, google-api, google-ads-api

Today is the first time this happened:

```
suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: '[RequestError.UNSUPPORTED_VERSION @ ; trigger:'You are accessing an AdWords API version v201708 that has been discontinued. Calls to this version may fail. Please visit the AdWords API blog for information on migration to the new AdWords API version.']'
```

It makes sense as it is announced [here](http://www.googblogs.com/adwords-api-v201705-and-v201708-sunset-reminder/) that it was sunset a few days ago.

So I changed the string to `"v201802"` as they recommend, now it gives a different error

```
googleads.errors.GoogleAdsValueError: Unrecognized version for the AdWords API. Given: v201802 Supported: ['v201702', 'v201609', 'v201708', 'v201705']
```

It only supports versions which appear to be deprecated.

Relevant output from `pip freeze` is:

```
apiclient==1.0.3
google-api-python-client==1.6.0
googleads==7.0.0
```

but not sure it has anything to do with that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`pip install --upgrade googleads` seems to have fixed it. New version `googleads==11.0.0` Went with the API version string `"v201710"` which was accepted after `googleads` was updated. Nothing else needed to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Working on google ads have been a bit tuff but this problem has a very simple solution.As we just need to switch the version.

1 - Update the **googleads** libs:
    **pip install --upgrade googleads**

2 - You need to change **`v201802`** to **`v201809`** everywhere this code has been used.

WHY - **`v201809`** is the latest version relased in september.

`campaign_service = client.GetService('CampaignService', version='v201809')`